# Find Conditional PDF and joint PDF from given independent random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given X: is a uniformly distributed R.V on [a,b], Y is a exponential R.V with parameter $\lambda$.

X, Y are independent and Z = X+Y, Is the given information enough to determine?

1. $f_{Z|Y}(z|y)$
2. $f_{Z,Y}(z,y)$

If it is enough, please help me to suggest how to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, saying they are independent and giving their distributions fully specifies the joint behavior of $X$ and $Y,$ so in principle, you have enough information to compute anything pertaining to them.

We can compute the conditional CDF as:
$$P(Z\le z\mid Y=y) = P(X+Y\le z\mid Y=y) \\= P(X+y\le z\mid Y=y) \\= P(X+y\le z) \\= P(X\le z-y)$$
where I used the condition to change $Y$ to $y$ and then used independence to drop the conditional. And you know the distribution of $X$...

You can get the first answer from this, and the second follows from the first by definition.

Comment: X is a uniformly distributed then
$P(X\le z-y)$ = (z-y). am I right?
And what is the range for $f_{Z}(z)$

Comment: @greenworld That's right. Not sure what you mean by the range of $f_Z(z).$ $Z=X+Y$ so you should be able to tell the possible values of $Z$ from that, if that's what you mean. You really want the possible values of $Z$ conditional on $Y=y$ though... so in that case you fix $Z = X+y$ where $X\in [a,b],$ so you get a range for $Z$ that depends on $y$.

Comment: How can I derive $f_{Z|Y}(z|y)$ from $P(X\le z-y)$?, I think about taking derivative but I am still confused.

Comment: @greenworld Like in the unconditional case, the conditional PDF is the derivative of the conditional CDF. Also, I made a mistake last comment. While $P(X\le z -y) = z-y$ when $X$ is U(0,1), this needs some modification for $U(a,b).$ But in any event, it might be better to notice $P(X\le z-y)  = F_X(z-y)$ and then say $f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}F_X(z-y) = F'_X(z-y)$ and then use the aforementioned fact that the derivative of the CDF is the PDF.

Comment: Thanks, it really helpful, can you suggest me some useful books about this topic?

Comment: @greenworld There are a lot of introductory probability books. The most used seems to be Ross, but I don't have any experience that would make me recommend it more or less than the others.

Comment: I did not see this formula: $f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}F_X(z-y)$ (derive conditional PDF from its CDF) in any textbook, so I am confused about the variable of the partial derivation.

Comment: @greenworld That formula is completely specific to this problem. The general formula it comes from is $$ f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}F_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y).$$ This is just the PDF being the derivative of the CDF... conditional distributions work just like unconditional ones where the variables we condition on behave like parameters. I was tempted to use a regular derivative rather than a partial since $y$ should be viewed more like a parameter than a variable in $f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y)$

Answer (score 0):

Well $f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y)=\left\lVert\dfrac{\partial [z-y,y]}{\partial [z,y]}\right\rVert\cdot f_{X\mid Y}(z-y\mid y)$

Now, since $X\perp Y$ therefore $f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y)=f_{X}(z-y)$

So $f_{Z,Y}(z,y)$ is clearly $f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)$ and hence you may determine $f_Z(z)$.

Comment: Your derivation is quite interesting. Actually, I did not learn this knowledge in my lecture, could you please suggest me a textbook referred to this?